# firebase.auth().currentUser returning null

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

In the html file that I have for the sign-in page, I perform the authentication using Firebase and on successful authentication, I redirect the given user to the homepage. When I call `firebase.auth().currentUser` in the express file, I use for rendering and routing pages, I get undefined or `null` for the current user.

Can anyone help me understand what the issue might be?

This is how I perform the authentication:

```
firebase
                .auth()
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(temail, tpass)
                .then(function(firebaseUser) {
                    window.location.href = "http://localhost:5000/homepage";
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    window.alert("incorrect pass");
                });
```

This is the code that I have in my express file:

```
app.get("/homepage", (req, res) => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    console.log("USER IS " + user);
    res.render("menu", { title: "Welcome" });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Backend code doesn't have a sense of "current user".  When you sign in on the frontend, the current user is only known on that client.  It isn't known on the backend.  If you want the backend to know which user is signed in, the client will have to send an ID token to the backend for it to verify.  The documentation for the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) is used for that on the backend.  The client must send the ID token to in the request to your route, and the code handling that route must [verify the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) in order to know the user that made the request.  From the documentation:

> If your Firebase client app communicates with a custom backend server, you might need to identify the currently signed-in user on that server. To do so securely, after a successful sign-in, send the user's ID token to your server using HTTPS. Then, on the server, verify the integrity and authenticity of the ID token and retrieve the uid from it. You can use the uid transmitted in this way to securely identify the currently signed-in user on your server.

Answer (score 1):

When the user lands on a new page, Firebase automatically restores their previous authentication state. But to do so, it may have to contact the server, which means that it may take a few moments. While Firebase is restoring the state, `auth().currentUser` will be null.

To ensure you get the correct authentication state, you should use an authentication state listener, as shown in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Comment: I changed the code in my express file to this, instead of var user = firebase.auth().currentUser. Now, even after a successful login, the user is NULL and it always goes in the else condition.

Comment: The `onAuthStateChanged` gets called for every auth state, so also initially with `null`. Once it restores the user session, it will then fire again with a user. You'll want to capture that fact in your code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - How can I check if the restoration of the user session is complete or not regardless of whether it is null or not? In the case where one does not want to subscribe to any state changes(one time use case). I've read this https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/462 and I am really disappointed as this is 3 years old.