# Firebase onAuthStateChanged user returns null when on localhost

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I've had a React website running on Firebase for over a year and implemented signInWithRedirect successfully several months ago.  However, as of last week, I can no longer log in to my site on localhost despite making no changes to my sign-in code.  It appears that the issue resides with the sign-in state observer, onAuthStateChanged, which returns the user as null in my testing.

Again, no changes were made to my sign-in code.  I have verified:

- that localhost and localhost:3000 are Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs in console.cloud.google.com under my project
- that localhost remains an Authorized domain in my Firebase project
- on my deployed site, where no changes were made, I can log in without any issue (issue seems to be isolated to localhost)

I am running Firebase 9.22.2, but I've also tried updating it to 10.4.0 without any change in behavior.

My code:

```
    const handleGoogleSignIn = async () => {
        await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
    };

    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
        if (user) {
            const result = await getRedirectResult(auth);
            if (result) {
                const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
                const token = credential.accessToken;
                const user = result.user;
                const expirationTime = user.stsTokenManager.expirationTime;
                const photo = user.photoURL;
                const userName = user.displayName;
                const email = user.email;
            }
        }
    });

    return (
        <Button variant='contained' onClick={handleGoogleSignIn}>
            Log In
        </Button>
    );
```

When I log in via `signInWithRedirect` I am properly taken away to log in and then redirected back to my localhost:3000 page, and I enter the `onAuthStateChanged` properly which I can tell since I've tested putting a `console.log(user)` at the beginning of that code block.  However, when I `console.log(user)` before the `if(user)` statement, it returns null every time since last week and it will not enter the `if(user)` block as it previously did.

Has anyone else had this issue recently?  Any suggestions on what else to try?

Comment: The issue seems to be with return resolve with a redirect, please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149287/firebase-auth-currentuser-is-null-when-loading-the-page-user-loaded-when-authst) and [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74145464/how-can-i-check-for-an-already-logged-in-user-on-initial-render-using-firestore), Also have  a look at [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)  and [similar link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536661/firebase-auth-currentuser-returning-null)

Comment: I'm sitting with the same issue, and suspect a change in Browser behaviour. It doesn't work for me in Chrome or Firefox, but does in Edge. Additionally i tested in Chrome on an old PC and it worked there, then updated Chrome and It stopped working again.

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar - I reviewed those links and it seems my setup is the same as they describe. Are you seeing a difference that I am missing?

Comment: @Hiws - Your comment helped tremendously.  I was not able to get localhost to be able to log in using Chrome (version 117.0.5938.149), Edge, or Firefox which are all up to date on my computer.  I rolled Chrome back to version 104.0.5112.101 and it worked correctly.  This does appear to be related to a browser issue.  Now the question is how to get Firebase to fix this for localhost testing.

Answer (score 5):

I contacted Firebase support and after submitting HAR files of the issue with logging into localhost via Firebase, they were able to identify this issue and provide the solution below which works for me.

> Our engineering team has been investigating the issue and has
> determined that it's due to the Third Party Storage partitioning
> that's enabled by default in modern web browsers. This partitioning is
> designed to mitigate the ability of websites to abuse state for
> cross-site tracking. However, it also affects the emulator's ability
> to successfully finish the redirect auth flow.
>
> To fix this behavior on Chrome, you can disable the Third Party
> Storage partitioning by going to the following settings:
>
> `chrome://flags/#third-party-storage-partitioning`
>
> For Firefox, you can fix the cookie partition behavior by modifying
> the following setting:
>
> `about:config > network.cookie.cookieBehavior`
>
> Change the value of this setting from 5 to 4.